# How to insert a row based on if statement within a Dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, and I want df1 (Both shown below). For each ID value, I want both drink types (Beer & Wine) to be represented. If any ID value does not have these, them insert the missing Drink Type and 'Not Stated' into the 'Drink' Column.

```
df:    

ID    DrinkType    Drink

130   Beer         Fosters
130   Wine         Rose
130   Beer         Budweiser 
102   Beer         Fosters
120   Wine         Pinot Grigot
120   Beer         Budweiser 
99    Wine         Coke
75    Beer         Carling
75    Beer         Fosters


df1:    

ID    DrinkType    Drink

130   Beer         Fosters
130   Wine         Rose
130   Beer         Budweiser 
102   Beer         Fosters   
102   Wine         Not Stated
120   Wine         Pinot Grigot
120   Beer         Budweiser 
99    Wine         Coke   
99    Beer         Not Stated
75    Beer         Carling
75    Beer         Fosters
75    Wine         Not Stated
```

Comment: why you are asking this question again ?? you want to be as logic or what

Comment: The answer was useful, but I still couldn't get it to work!

Comment: Do you know how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your required sol

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Id':[130,130,130,102,120,120,99,75,75],'DrinkType': 
['Beer','Wine','Beer','Beer','Wine','Beer','Wine','Beer','Beer'],'Drink': 
                            ['Fosters','Rose','Budweiser','Fosters','PinotGrigot','Budweiser','Coke','Carling','Fosters']})

diff=df['Id'].unique()
print(diff)

all_cate={'Beer','Wine'}

for i in diff:
    inte=all_cate.intersection(set(df.loc[df['Id']==i,'DrinkType'].unique()))
    for j in all_cate:
        if(j not in inte):
            print((i,j,'NotStated'))
            df=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({'Id':[i],'DrinkType':[j],'Drink': 
                                                                     ['NotStated']})])


df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]